# Android Studio Add external resource

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, libgdx, shared-resource

I am working on an android app, which is based on libgdx framework.
I need to test the app on my pc, so I set up Android Studio to build me an apk or a normal java jar.
But I need to pack my resources (images, audio, allways the same for both) into both, apk and jar. How can I share those resources between those two projects?

Comment: Create link in one project to resources from the second project

Comment: Are you using Gradle to build your desktop app? If not, how are you building it?

Comment: Thanks. I actually resolved it by removing Gradle and letting it autogenerate the configuration. Now I'm able to share resources and include files in my projects.